# C++11: istream.get() stops on EOM

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, istream

I have a problem with c++(11) inputstreams, specifically filestreams. After I open a new stream with this:

```
ifstream stream;
stream.open("C:\somefile.txt");
```

And when I try to read from it and the read operation encounters and EOM-byte (0x19) the stream is set to badbit which is not what I want. I want to read until the definit end of the file. This is how I read

```
char buffer[8];
stream.read(buffer, 8);
```

and then I check like that:

```
if(stream.fail()) return -1;
```

How can I read from the stream without stopping at EOM-bytes (or equal)?

Comment: How big is the file? Maybe you have already tried to read from beyond the end of the file? Can you please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file as a binary stream instead:

```
ifstream stream{ "C:\\somefile.txt", std::ios::binary };
```

This should cause the stream to ignore the value of individual bytes, on reading (and simply read as a block).